# plyr to calculate relative aggregration

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
> head(activity_data)
ev_id cust_id active previous_active start_date
1 1141880     201      1               0 2008-08-17
2 4927803     201      1               0 2013-03-17
3 1141880     244      1               0 2008-08-17
4 2391524     244      1               0 2011-02-05
5 1141868     325      1               0 2008-08-16
6 1141872     325      1               0 2008-08-16
```

- for each cust_id

  - for each ev_id

    - create a new variable $recent_active (= sum $active across all rows with this cust_id where $start_date > [this_row]$start_date - 10)

I am struggling to do this using ddply, as my split grouping was .(cust_id) and I wanted to return rows with cust_id and ev_id

Here is what I tried

```
ddply(activity_data, .(cust_id), function(x) recent_active=sum(x[this_row,]$active))
```

If ddply is not an option what other effieicent ways do you recommend. My dataset has ~200mn rows and I need to do this about 10-15 times per row.

sample data is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9WV6WVs9KBdbUpaTmU4OElFQUk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I recoomand using `data.table`, can you give us a reproducible example so we can write the answer on actual data ?

Comment: In `$start_date > [this_row]$start_date - 10)` what is the 10? 10 days or 10 months or 10 years? and please `dput` the sample data.

Comment: dput for a subset.                   structure(list(ev_id = c(1144095L, 4930018L, 1144095L, 2393739L, 
1144083L, 1144087L, 1144099L, 1144101L, 1190816L, 1190818L), 
    cust_id = c(201L, 201L, 244L, 244L, 325L, 325L, 325L, 325L, 
    325L, 325L), active = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), previous_active = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), start_date = structure(c(14334, 
    16007, 14334, 15236, 14333, 14333, 14333, 14333, 14340, 14341
    ), class = "Date")), .Names = c("ev_id", "cust_id", "active", 
"previous_active", "start_date"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use two step approach here (and also need to convert date into date format before using the following code)

```
ddply(activity_date, .(cust_id), transform, recent_active=your function) #Not clear what you are asking regarding the function

ddply(activity_date, .(cust_id,ev_id), summarize,recent_active=sum(recent_active))
```